# The universe contains broken links

Tags: business-objects

So, I have edited a business and data foundation layer. Now I decided to rename both of them. Problem is - when I want to publish the universe I get the error message: "The universe contains broken links. Fix the links and try publishing the universe again."

Then I rigt-clicked on the business layer and selected "Show Local Dependencies -> Referenced Resources". There I see the renamed version of data foundation, but also the previous version that even does not exist in the folder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: million dollar question: why does one have to be a rocket scientist to work with BO?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the name of data foundation have you mapped the business layer to newly data fo

Comment: can you tell me in plain english how to rename both business layer and data foundation layer so that both of them function afterwards?

Comment: Double click on business layer/data foundation-> go to the properties->change the name.  The name of datafoundationa and business layer in local project can we any thing but whatever name is there in property of business layer, it will become a universe name.